Prove convergence of $\limsup_{n\to\infty}$
I am new to Real Analysis, and I have found this problem hard to formalize.
Problem
Let $(p_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ and $(q_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ sequences such that $(p_n)\to u$ and $(q_n)\to v$. Consider the sequence $(x_n)_{n\in\mathbb{N}}$ such that $x_n:=\begin{cases}q_m\text{ if } n = 2m-1\\ p_m\text{ if } n = 2m\end{cases}$. Show that $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\max\{u, v\}$, and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n=\min\{u, v\}$.
My attempt
I begin dividing into two cases. Either $u = v$, or $u\neq v$. For the first case, it seems easy to conclude that since every subsequence converges to $u=v$, then $\lim_{n\to\infty}x_n=\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=\liminf_{n\to\infty}x_n=u=v$.
For the second case, without loss of generality let $u>v$. We want to show then, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}=u$ and $\liminf_{n\to\infty}=v$.
Let us start with the first aim (as the limit inferior could be proved analogously):
Since $u>v$, $\exists\epsilon_1>0: u > v + \epsilon_1.\tag{1}$
Since $q_{m}\to v$ and $p_{m}\to u$, for all $\epsilon>0$, $\exists M_q$ s.t. $m>M_q, |x_{2m-1}-v|<\epsilon$, and $\exists M_p$ s.t. $m>M_p, |x_{2m}-u|<\epsilon$.
Let $\epsilon>0$. Set $M=\max\{M_q, M_p\}$. Then, for $m>M$, $|x_{2m-1}-v|<\epsilon$ and $|x_{2m}-u|<\epsilon$, i.e.: $$v-\epsilon<x_{2m-1}<v+\epsilon\quad\text{ and }\quad u-\epsilon<x_{2m}<u+\epsilon.$$
If $\epsilon<\frac{\epsilon_1}{2}$, $$v-\epsilon<x_{2m-1}<v+\epsilon<v+\frac{\epsilon_1}{2}\quad\text{ and }\quad u-\frac{\epsilon_1}{2}<u-\epsilon<x_{2m}<u+\epsilon,$$
and because of (1), $$v-\epsilon<x_{2m-1}<v+\epsilon<v+\frac{\epsilon_1}{2}<u-\frac{\epsilon_1}{2}<u-\epsilon<x_{2m}<u+\epsilon,$$ that is, $x_{2m-1}<u-\epsilon<x_{2m}<u+\epsilon$ for all $m>M$.
Let $i>2M$ and $s_i=\sup(\{x_k\}_{k\geq i})$, then $s_i>u-\epsilon$ because $u-\epsilon$ is not an upper bound of $\{x_k\}_{k\geq i}$. On the other hand, $s_i\leq u+\epsilon$, since it is an upper bound. Therefore,
for $0<\epsilon<\frac{\epsilon_1}{2}$ and $i>2M$, $$u-\epsilon < s_i \leq u+\epsilon\tag{2}\Rightarrow|s_i-u|\leq\epsilon.$$ Now, $\limsup_{n\to\infty}x_n=u$ if the inequality in (2) is strict, but I cannot see how to overcome this issue.
And the other concern is: what happens when $\epsilon>\epsilon_1/2$? My intuition is that we can set the same $M$ as for any $\epsilon^{\ast}<\epsilon_1/2$, and that ensures $|s_i-u|<\epsilon^{\ast}<\epsilon$ for any $\epsilon>0$. But how can I state this fact rigorously?
I feel this proof can probably be shortened and/or better written, so any improvement or advice is more than welcome.

Your proof is good, sorry I did not read it carefully earlier. I fell in love with the subsequence proof, but adding in the subsequence characterization made it pretty long.
To address the issue with $|s_i-u|\leq \epsilon$ in equation (2). Between “Let $\epsilon>0$” and up to an including equation (2), replace $\epsilon$ with $\epsilon/2.$ Then  $|s_i-u|\leq \epsilon$ becomes $|s_i-u|\leq \epsilon/2<\epsilon$. If you end up with $\,$ but need $<$, this trick almost always works.
The other issue you mention is what happens when $\epsilon\geq\epsilon_1/2$ (now $\epsilon/2\geq\epsilon_1/2.$) In this case the $M$ you found to work for $\epsilon=\epsilon_1/4$ will work. This type of argument is the reason you always can assume $\epsilon$ is small, at least smaller than any fixed number $>0$.
Let me know if you need more clarification.

Using that subsequences of convergent sequence converges to the same limit as the original sequence.
The limit superior is the largest limit of any convergent subsequence and the limit inferior is the smallest limit of any convergent subsequence.
As you state, we can assume $u>v.$
The subsequence $x_{2m-1}=q_m\to v$ and the subsequence $x_{2m}=p_m\to u.$ It remains to show than any convergent subsequence must converge to $u$ or to $v$.
Suppose $x_{n_m}\to w.$ If infinitely many $n_m$ are odd, then those odd subscripts gives a subsequence $\left(x_{n_{m_k}}\right)$ of $(x_{n_m})$ thus $x_{n_{m_k}}\to w$ and since $\left(x_{n_{m_k}}\right)$ also is a subsequence of $(x_{2m-1})$ also $x_{n_{m_k}}\to v.$ Thus $w=v.$ Similarly, if infinitely many $n_m$ are even, then $w=v.$ In particular, if infinitely many $n_m$ are both even and odd then $u=v.$
ADDED a proof of the claim in the second paragraph above.
Since $(x_{2m-1})$ and $(x_{2m})$ are convergent they are bounded, so $(x_n)$ is bounded and has convergent subsequences.
Let
$
    b:=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\{x_k \mid k\geq n\}
$
be the limit superior of $(x_n).$ Below I will prove the claims
Claim (C): Every convergent subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges to a number $\leq b.$
Claim (D): Some subsequence of $(x_n)$ converges to $b.$
Combining (C) and (D) it follows that the limit superior is the largest limit of any convergent subsequence of $(x_n).$
PROOF of (C):  Suppose $\left(x_{n_k}\right)$ is a subsequence of $(x_n)$ converging to some number $a.$
Since $x_{n_\ell}\to a$, for any $\varepsilon>0,$  there  is a $L,$ such that $a-\varepsilon < x_{n_{\ell}}$ for all $\ell > L.$  Hence, the sets
$\{x_k \mid k\geq n\}$ all contain at least one $x_{n_{\ell}}  > a-\varepsilon.$  So, for any $n$ we have
$\sup\{x_k \mid k\geq n\} > a-\varepsilon.$ Therefore $b=\lim_{n\to\infty} \sup\{x_k \mid k\geq n\} \geq a-\varepsilon.$  Since $\varepsilon>0$ is arbitrary, $b\geq a.$
EndOfProof
PROOF of (D):
Since $\sup\{x_k \mid k\geq n\}\to b$ as $n\to\infty$, for any $\varepsilon>0,$ there is an $N,$ such that $b-\varepsilon < \sup\{x_k \mid k\geq n\} < b+\varepsilon$ for all $n>N.$  Hence the set $\{x_k \mid k\geq n\}$ has en element $b-\varepsilon < x_k  < b+\varepsilon$, so:
For any $\varepsilon>0$ and any $n$, there is an $k\geq n$ such that $b-\varepsilon < x_k < b+\varepsilon$.
I will use this with various choices for $\varepsilon$ and $n.$
Pick $n_1$ such that $b-\frac{1}{1}< x_{n_1} < b+\frac{1}{1}$  ($\varepsilon=\frac{1}{1},n=1$).
Pick $n_2>n_1$ such that $b-\frac{1}{2}< x_{n_2} < b+\frac{1}{2}$ ($\varepsilon=\frac{1}{2},n=1+n_1$).
Pick $n_3>n_2$ such that $b-\frac{1}{3}< x_{n_3} < b+\frac{1}{3}$  ($\varepsilon=\frac{1}{3},n=1+n_2$).
Continuing in this fashion (proof by induction) we get $n_1<n_2<n_3<\cdots$ such that
$b-\frac{1}{k}< x_{n_k} < b+\frac{1}{k}$ for all $k.$ Hence $x_{n_k}\to b.$
EndOfProof

Is this answering the question?

The largest limit of a subsequence is the limit superior. And the smallest the limit inferior. Will edit my answer to reflect this.

Yes, but I think this is essentially what is being asked to be proved.

I agree with @J.S. I would like to use this problem as a solid stone to prove the somehow equivalent result you are using: "The limit superior is the largest limit of any convergent subsequence and the limit inferior is the smallest limit of any convergent subsequence."

No problem. Will be a few hours before I have free time to type it up.

@Steen82 Thank you very much for your complete proof.
